# Which stack is the most appropriate for questions related to nautical-electrical issues?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

My boat has a GPS and a tiller pilot, which seem to work fine separately, but don't seem to want to talk to one-another.

Which stack would be most suitable to ask about such nautical-electrical issues?

Comment: Outdoors.se maybe? They have boating on their list: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic but it might be that your specific question is more hands on

Comment: Most SE sites don't want to get their feet wet ...

Comment: @rene Except [Law SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/users/10/feetwet) apparently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your description, [Outdoors Stack Exchange](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/) will be your best bet, but remember we do have an [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/3525/) if you have a question that needs an answer at the voltage and current flow end of things :-)

Answer (score 2):

I recently asked a question about [cabin power supplies on cruise ships](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/26645/what-is-it-about-the-cabin-electrical-supply-on-cruise-ships-that-makes-surge-pr) and got a good answer.  This was the Engineering.SE site, with tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, and marine-engineering.

Comment: Hm, my question got closed as off topic in Electrical. Trying in Outdoors.

Comment: "closed as off topic in Electrical" -- Note that I suggested "Engineering", not "Electrical".

Comment: Ah. *headdesk* silly me.